# How do you retrieve a theme from the monaco editor?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

Basically what the title is asking. I know that `monaco.editor.setTheme()` and `.defineTheme()` exist, but how would one retrieve the JSON or the object that defines the theme that is currently being used, or the JSONs/objects of other stored themes in the browser?

Comment: The unofficial way is `editor._themeService._theme.themeName`

Comment: And to get all possible themes: `editor._themeService._knownThemes.keys()`

Answer (score -1):

Update: The unofficial way to retrieve the current theme in monaco-editor as of version 0.21.2 is `editor._themeService._theme`

---

Note: in monaco-editor version (0.21.2), `editor._themeService.getTheme()` throws an error.

`Uncaught Error: editor._themeService.getTheme is not a function`